# Dynamically get product title from database and place in URL codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am working in code igniter framework. I want to dynamically get product title from database by passing ID like in stackoverflow. As we see in SO, when I erase title and hit enter then title in automatically generated in URL. How is this working. After googling I found it can be done by using .htaccess but I cannot get how I can achieve it.

My .htaccess is:

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any example and tutorials would be helpful. THank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do cannot be accomplished using an htaccess file as it a bit more involved. That being said its not real difficult. The below will convert a url such as:

```
http://example.com/store/product/33
```

to

```
http://example.com/store/product/33/some-product-title
```

Database:

[image]

Controller:

```
class store extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model('store_model','store');

    }

    function product($id, $slug=''){

        //if no slug value passed then we obtain the product title and redirect
        if($slug === ''){

            //get the title value from products table and run it through _slugify function
            $slug = $this->_slugify($this->store->read_productTitle($id));

            redirect('store/product/'. $id . '/' . $slug);

        }

        //The rest of your logic will go here, then you will load your view. For the purpose
        //of examples I'm just going to echo a string.
        echo "This is a string";

    }

    function _slugify($text){ 

        //YOU CAN CHANGE THIS FUNCTION TO FORMAT THE TITLE VALUE HOWEVER
        //YOU WANT IT TO APPEAR IF THIS DOESN'T WORK FOR YOU. ALSO, THIS FUNCTION
        //WOULD MAKE MORE SENSE IN A HELPER FILE.

        // replace non letter or digits by -
        $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

        // trim
        $text = trim($text, '-');

        // transliterate
        $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

        // lowercase
        $text = strtolower($text);

        // remove unwanted characters
        $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

        if (empty($text))
        {
          return 'n-a';
        }

        return $text;
    }

}
```

Model:

```
class store_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function read_productTitle($id){
        $query = "SELECT ProductTitle"
                . " FROM products"
                . " WHERE ProductID = ?";

        $bindArray = array($id);

        $query_result = $this->db->query($query, $bindArray);

        return $query_result->row()->ProductTitle;

    }

}
```

If you are wanting to remove the controller name from the url you can do that by creating a custom route in /application/config/routes.php

Comment: This is not what I want. I like same like stackoverflow where when I erase title also from url then it fetches url title from database and rewrites it to url. It may be by .htaccess.

Comment: Original answer has been updated with detailed example code explaining how to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: what happens if user erases the title only in url and press enter. does it automatically generated title like SO does.

Comment: Yes. You can see this in the controller function product. There is logic that checks if the url is being submitted without the slug and if so then it obtains the slug and redirects back to itself. This is explained in the comments.

Comment: Your answer worked for me. But, what can I do incase in want to route the url. Like insted of `redirect('store/product/'. $id . '/' . $slug);`. I want to use `redirect('product/'. $id . '/' . $slug);` and in routes config I did `$route['product/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'store/product/$1';` then I get webpage has redirect loop. How can I do it.

Comment: $route['product/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'store/product/$1/$2';

Comment: I don't want to show 33 number. I want to set my url  'http://example.com/store/product/some-product-title'. But I want to get get number. How route should be